# Removing blank line in-between two bulletin values

Tags: html

I'm getting the html values to get display on UI. But I'm getting the blank line in-between two bulletins values.

```
<ul><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li></ul>
```

This will display values as below

•Coffee

•Tea

But my expectations would be

```
•Coffee
•Tea
```

Is there any way to met my expectations in html tags instead of using CSS?

Comment: Can you please add a [mre]? I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just make a bare example without any CSS and see that what you want is actually default. If you’re seeing a space between the list items, there must a CSS declaration somewhere that creates a margin between them.

Comment: if you are using a base HTML page it should not do that. If you are using some sort of content from another place with CSS or something else, that could be the problem. Please provide a minimum reproductive code to assist you with better results.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For my knowledge, pure html cannot achieve that, but how about inline style?

```
<ul><li>Coffee</li><li style="margin-top:0;">Tea</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also ran through the code but I didn't have the same problem as you, a blank line does not appear between the two values

```js
<ul><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li></ul>
```

> •Coffee
> •Tea

Did you set some other css style that caused it to produce blank lines?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code to know if you are applying some default CSS styling to this content. By default, this should not be happening.
For confirmation just check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Styling_lists)